# Computing a series with another series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was asked to compute this series:

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{\left(2n-1\right)^2}$

but by using the fact that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi ^2}{6}$

I think i know how to compute the series by itself by using the telescoping test but I am not sure how to use the second series...I know it must have something to do with power series but any help to get started would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By direct calculation, we see that
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^2} = \sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}+\frac{1}{4}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}=\frac{3}{4}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{3}{4}\frac{\pi^2}{6} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Observe that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)^2}=\frac{1}{(2\cdot1)^2}+\frac{1}{(2\cdot2)^2}+\frac{1}{(2\cdot3)^2}\dotsb
=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\dotsb\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{4(6)}.
$$
But
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}
$$
where rearrangement is allowed since we are dealing with non-negative series.